# Copy specific vector parts c++

Tags: c++, vector, copy-paste

I want to reorder a vector into an specific way, for example, for the next vector

```
vector<int> v=[100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107]
```

I have 6 index : `i1=0,i2=1, j1=3,j2=4,k1=5,k2=6` and the new vector I want is:

```
v1=[100,104,105,101,102,103,106,107]
```

Using index it would be something like:

```
v1=[ v[0]to v[i1],v[j2] to v[k1], v[i2] to v[j1], v[k2] to v[end]]
```

All i have found is a way to copy a part:

```
vector<int> v2(v.begin() + x, v.begin() + x + y);
```

So, anyone knows how to get what I want?

Comment: As for me then I have understood nothing, What are i1, i2, j1, j2, k1, k2?

Comment: Index, which point out parts of vector  i want to copy

Comment: Is this a from-to range? I think you should expand your question a bit, giving more precise information about how you want that reordering to happen. Maybe some more examples would help, too. Also, do you want to make a copy or move the values? What about values not referred to by any index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>`, if you know your indices exactly, and you are just reordering:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[] = {100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107};
    vector<int> v(arr, arr + 8);

    // your 6 indices:
    int i1=0, i2=1, j1=3, j2=4, k1=5, k2=6;

    // a copy vector:
    vector<int> v1(v.size()); // make sure to reserve enough size

    vector<int>::iterator v1end = v1.begin(); // where to copy

    // copy your ranges
    v1end = copy(v.begin(), v.begin() + i2 + 1, v1end);
    v1end = copy(v.begin() + j2, v.begin() + k1 + 1, v1end);
    v1end = copy(v.begin() + i2, v.begin() + j1 + 1, v1end);
    v1end = copy(v.begin() + k2, v.end(), v1end);

    // print the output
    copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess the actual indices aren't known at compile time, or this reordering might be needed multiple times with different indices.

Comment: This would work if the actual indices are not known at compile time too, but you'd have to be more careful. For example, you'd probably use `back_inserter` instead of `ostream_iterator`

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I meant also the count of indices. But it seems the question is solved :)